# How can I create stacked line graph?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to be able to produce a stacked line graph (similar to the method used [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20090901073911/http://www.whitehouse.gov/omb/budget/fy2003/images/bud20c.jpg)) with Python (preferably using matplotlib, but another library would be fine too).  How can I do this?

This similar to the [stacked bar graph example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/bar_stacked.html) on their website, except I'd like the top of bar to be connected with a line segment and the area underneath to be filled.  I might be able to approximate this by decreasing the gaps between bars and using lots of bars (but this seems like a hack, and besides I'm not sure if it is possible).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I believe ***Area Plot*** is a common term for this type of plot, and in the specific instance recited in the OP, ***Stacked Area Plot***.

Matplotlib does not have an "out-of-the-box" function that combines *both* the data processing and drawing/rendering steps to create a this type of plot, but it's easy to roll your own from components supplied by Matplotlib and NumPy.

The code below first ***stacks*** the data, then ***draws*** the plot.

```
import numpy as NP
from matplotlib import pyplot as PLT

# just create some random data
fnx = lambda : NP.random.randint(3, 10, 10)
y = NP.row_stack((fnx(), fnx(), fnx()))   
# this call to 'cumsum' (cumulative sum), passing in your y data, 
# is necessary to avoid having to manually order the datasets
x = NP.arange(10) 
y_stack = NP.cumsum(y, axis=0)   # a 3x10 array

fig = PLT.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax1.fill_between(x, 0, y_stack[0,:], facecolor="#CC6666", alpha=.7)
ax1.fill_between(x, y_stack[0,:], y_stack[1,:], facecolor="#1DACD6", alpha=.7)
ax1.fill_between(x, y_stack[1,:], y_stack[2,:], facecolor="#6E5160")

PLT.show()
```

---

[image: example of stacked area plot]

Answer (score 71):

Newer versions of matplotlib contain the function [`plt.stackplot()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.stackplot.html), which allows for several different "out-of-the-box" stacked area plots:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

X = np.arange(0, 10, 1) 
Y = X + 5 * np.random.random((5, X.size))

baseline = ["zero", "sym", "wiggle", "weighted_wiggle"]
for n, v in enumerate(baseline):
    plt.subplot(2 ,2, n + 1)
    plt.stackplot(X, *Y, baseline=v)
    plt.title(v)
    plt.axis('tight')
plt.show()
```

[image: Stack plot using plt.stackplot.]

Answer (score 16):

If you have a dataframe, it's quite easy:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 4), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
df.plot.area();
```

[image]

From: [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html)

Comment: Thank you. Plain and simple. Best practice!

Answer (score 9):

A slightly less hackish way would be to use a line graph in the first place and `matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between`. To emulate the stacking you have to shift the points up yourself.

```
x = np.arange(0,4)
y1 = np.array([1,2,4,3])
y2 = np.array([5,2,1,3])
# y2 should go on top, so shift them up
y2s = y1+y2

plot(x,y1)
plot(x,y2s)
fill_between(x,y1,0,color='blue')
fill_between(x,y1,y2s,color='red')
```